# Removing <uses-feature> doesn't remove it from for Google Play

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, uses-feature

I am developing an app for Android, and, after uploading it to Google Play, I realised that I was not depending on a `<uses-feature>` anymore, so I removed it. To be more specific, I was coding a Camera Activity, so I needed these features:

```
android.hardware.CAMERA
android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS
```

However, after that, I decided to go for the Camera Intent. That's why I removed them.

My surprise comes when I see that the APK Information modal shows that it is still using those features, even if they aren't in my Manifest.

My question is, does that mean that I will "need" those features, even if I removed them? Maybe because they are depending on the Camera Intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "figured it out". When you add a `android:required="false"` to the `<uses-feature>`, it becomes unnecessary and is removed from the APK information.

Answer (score 0):

Your Application uses those feature because you added `<uses-permission>` in your code.
Whenever you specify permission it access all the features until you uniquely not specify which features you exactly want to use in your application.

Comment: Well, maybe I didn't clarify it. After uploading the app, I realised I was using the Camera Intent, so I **removed** those two features

Comment: I think since Intent uses default camera app installed in device, it by default uses those features  so it require that features.

Comment: when you add `android:required="false"` to the `<uses-feature>`, Google Play allow the app to search/install for all the devices not for only those devices that have specific features.